# Disable reverse lookup in rsync daemon

Tags: rsync, reverse-dns

I'm having an issue with some rsync modules being served through `rsync --daemon`

This lines are from my /var/log/rsyncd.log file :

```
2013/02/08 12:15:28 [13174] name lookup failed for XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX: Name or service not known
2013/02/08 12:15:28 [13174] connect from UNKNOWN (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)
```

From rsyncd.conf man page:

> **reverse lookup**
>
> Controls whether the daemon performs a reverse lookup on the client's
>   IP address to determine its hostname, which is used for "hosts
>   allow"/"hosts deny" checks and the "%h" log escape. This is enabled by
>   default, but you may wish to disable it to save time if you know the
>   lookup will not return a useful result, in which case the daemon will
>   use the name "UNDETERMINED" instead.
>
> If this parameter is enabled globally (even by default), rsync
>   performs the lookup as soon as a client connects, so disabling it for
>   a module will not avoid the lookup. Thus, you probably want to disable
>   it globally and then enable it for modules that need the information.

So I added the following line to the global conf in /etc/rsyncd.conf

```
reverse lookup = no
```

But, when I stopped and started the daemon this lines where added to the log file:

```
2013/02/08 12:47:17 [13675] Unknown Parameter encountered: "reverse lookup" 
2013/02/08 12:47:17 [13675] IGNORING unknown parameter "reverse lookup" 
2013/02/08 12:47:17 [13676] rsyncd version 3.0.7 starting, listening on port 873
```

This is the version installed on my server:

> rsync  version 3.0.7  protocol version 30

Comment: The [Ubuntu manpage for 3.0.7](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man5/rsyncd.conf.5.html) doesn't list this option. Are you referring to the manpage from the same package as the version you're using?

Comment: No, I was referring to an online man page since I did't install `man`.
My bad

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `reverse lookup` option is only present in the [upcoming 3.1.0 release](http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/unpacked/rsync/NEWS):

> NEWS for rsync 3.1.0 (UNRELEASED)
>
> - Added the "reverse lookup" parameter to the rsync daemon config file to allow reverse-DNS lookups to be disabled.

Comment: Now it makes sense

Answer (score 5):

I don't think the option for turning off reverse dns lookup exists in rsync daemon. What you can do instead is put the client hosts and IP addresses in `/etc/hosts` , of course assuming that your clients have static IP and are a few hosts.

Answer (score -3):

Option "reverse lookup" only add on version from 3.1.0

Comment: This was answered already, two years ago.